# I can't make synthesis in Vivado

Tags: fft, http-live-streaming, vivado, ifft

I work in Vivado HLS, and I want to make a code of IFFT with a test bench. Can any one help me?

Comment: please clarify your question. What exactly do you want.

Comment: i have a code for FFT in c,and i want to build the same programme in systemC,i try to do this but he give me error in compilation example:fatal error: 'iostream.h' file not found
#include <iostream.h>

Comment: please donot write this in comments, but update you post and provide as much information as possible

Answer (score 1):

If you look into the examples provided with Vivado HLS, you will find an iFFT example with test bench. Assuming you are on a windows machine with the standard install paths C:\Xilinx\Vivado_HLS\2014.4\examples\design\FFT\fft_ifft or use Help > Welcome to copy the example from the Welsome page.